# Twitter Status updating Issue with oAuth in iPhone

Tags: ios4, twitter

Hope You all are fine and also in one of your best of moods.

I have an issue with twitter status updating.

As I am using oAuth API for Twitter Integration in my iPhone,  I found a sample code , and run it. code is quite useful, but i found the functionality for updating status is not working, and functionality of getting status works.

I found sample code from the link :

http://github.com/jaanus/PlainOAuth

I have tried lot, before posting this issue here. kindly have a look and help me out to solve the issue.

Looking Forwards. 
Arun Thakkar.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the specific problem is, but I remember having to do a fair amount of head-banging to get Twitter OAuth to work.

Nevertheless, I have a working implementation in one of my [public GitHub projects](https://github.com/mtabini/AFKSocialShare). Feel free to use it—apps based on it have already been approved into the App Store.